# MNIST with Tensorflow, ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am trying to run through the MNIST dataset with Tensorflow.  Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

X_train = np.array(mnist.train.images, 'float')
X_test = np.array(mnist.test.images, 'float')
y_train = np.array(mnist.train.images, 'int32')
y_test = np.array(mnist.test.images, 'int32')

# Specify feature
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('', dimension=784)]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns, 
                                            hidden_units=[200, 100, 60, 30], 
                                            n_classes=10,
                                            model_dir="./output"
                                            )

# Fit model.
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=100, steps=1000)

# Evaluate accuracy.
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(X_test, y_test)["accuracy"]

print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(accuracy_score))
```

However, I keep getting the error:

> ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 784
>   for 'dnn/multi_class_head/softmax_cross_entropy_loss/Squeeze' (op:
>   'Squeeze') with input shapes: [?,784].

The traceback is callingmy attention to line 31, which is where I call fit() on the classifier, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: One thing to point out: the labels (y_xxxx) should be in mnist.[train|test].labels, rather than mnist.[train|test].images

Comment: Thank you.  That was a copy and paste error I made while trying different things.  I have corrected that, but it still doesn't solve the error... however, I now get a slight different error, saying expected 1, got 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work OK tf.**version** = '1.1.0' and using python 3.6. There's probably some issue with the dimensionality of your input data, but work backward from this.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
import numpy as np

mnist_data = "save/here/mnist"

MNIST_DATASET = input_data.read_data_sets(mnist_data)

train_data = np.array(MNIST_DATASET.train.images, 'float32')
train_target = np.array(MNIST_DATASET.train.labels, 'int64')

test_data = np.array(MNIST_DATASET.test.images, 'float32')
test_target = np.array(MNIST_DATASET.test.labels, 'int64')

feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=784)]

classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=feature_columns
    ,n_classes=10
    ,hidden_units=[128, 32]
)

classifier.fit(train_data, train_target, steps=5)
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(test_data, test_target, steps=5)['accuracy']
print("accuracy: ", 100*accuracy_score,"%")
```

output:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Skipping summary for global_step, must be a float or np.float32.
accuracy:  44.3899989128 %
```

Comment: Okay, so it seems that the issue was with the "one_hot=True" call that I put in when reading the data.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, for anyone running the code above, just as a warning, if you increase the number of steps significantly, you will probably want to add batch_size = 100 into the classifier.fit() as it will save you lots of time.

Using batch_size=100 and Steps = 5000 in about 45 seconds you can get +/-98% accuracy